# Xcode when adding localization not all storyboards are found

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

When I try to add localization to my app by clicking on project-> localization -> + and add a new language the popup will only show two storyboards even though my app has three.

[image]

One storyboard file is missing from the popup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need do following steps :

1. First you need to create new string file.
2. after select this string file and In file inspector and click on Localize button . 
   then you can see string file along with storyboards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding Localizable.strings is a needed. If you still don't find some storyboards when adding a language, select the storyboards that don't appear and click **localize** button on the File Inspector in the right pane. Now when you add a new language the popup will show those missing storyboards

Answer (score 0):

I had to open my storyboard and add a base localization, then it would show up in the popup when I wanted to add a new language