# Main.storyboard not found when try to add localization

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

I tried to add localized my storyboard, but the Main.storyboard is not listed?

[image]

I clicked the "+", and I see only the LaunchScreen.storyboard

[image]

Only one know how can I add my storyboard to be localized?

### Super strange, I opened another project, and the Main.Storyboard is presented.

Comment: try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40585054/3901620 if it is useful for you then do upvote .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Main.storyboard` is in the `Base.lproj` folder